# Column of owner of webform submission in database

Tags: users, webforms

I need to find the column of the owner (user_id) of form submission in webforms. I need it in order to create some complex queries for the needs of the client. I looked in webform_submission_data and webform_submission tables but I was not able to find it. Does exist in some other table?

Answer (score 0):

found it, it was uid in webform_submission_data table. I couldnt find it, because it was hidden from phpmyadmin